Unable to use split. tryed doing with align got more error in that also due to this im unable to fit the equation the page
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
  J_{cp} &=& \frac{1}{36} \bigg[\sqrt{3} \sin (2 \text{$\phi' $}) (\sin (\sigma ) \cos (\text{$\sigma' $}) \sin (2 \phi )-2 \sin (\text{$\sigma' $}) \cos (2 \phi ))\\
  &\quad-3 \sin (\sigma ) \sin (2 \phi ) \cos (2 \text{$\phi' $})\bigg]\\
  I_{1} &=& \frac{1}{288}\bigg[\left. 2 \sqrt{3} \sin (\phi) \sin (2 \phi') \left( 8 \sin (2 \sigma) \cos (\sigma') \sin (\phi) \cos^2 (\phi) \right. \right. \\
  &\quad \left. \left. + 2 \sin (\sigma') \left( 8 \cos (\sigma) \cos^3 (\phi) - 4 \cos (2 \sigma) \sin (\phi) \cos^2 (\phi) + \sin (\phi) + 5 \sin (3 \phi) \right) \right. \right.\\
  &\quad \left. \left. - 4 \sin (\sigma) \cos (\sigma') (\cos (\phi) + 3 \cos (3 \phi)) \right) \right. \\
  &\quad \left. + 6 \cos (2 \phi') \left( \sin (4 \phi) (\sin (\sigma - 2 \sigma') - 3 \sin (\sigma)) \right. \right. \\
  &\quad \left. \left. + \cos (\sigma') (-4 \sin (2 \phi) \sin (\sigma - \sigma') + 2 \sin (\sigma) \cos (4 \phi) \cos (\sigma - \sigma') \right. \right. \\
  &\quad \left. \left. - \sin (2 \sigma - \sigma') + 3 \sin (\sigma')) - 2 \sin (2 \sigma') \cos (2 \phi) \right) \right. \\
  &\quad \left. - 24 \sin (2 \sigma') \sin^3 (\phi) (2 \cos (\sigma) \cos (\phi) + \sin (\phi)) \right. \\
  &\quad \left. - 12 \sin (2 \phi) \left( \sin (\sigma) (\cos (2 \sigma') + 3) \cos (2 \phi) + \sin (\sigma') (\sin (2 \phi) \cos (2 \sigma - \sigma')\right) \right) \\
  &\quad  \left. + 2 \sin (\sigma) \sin (\sigma')  \right.\bigg]\\
  I_{2} &=& \frac{1}{2304} \bigg[\left. 96 \cos (2 \phi') \left( \sin^3 (\phi) \left( 8 \sin (\sigma) \cos^2 (2 \sigma') \cos (\phi) \right. \right. \right.\\
  &\quad \left. \left. + \sin (4 \sigma') (\sin (\phi) - 4 \cos (\sigma) \cos (\phi)) \right) \right. \\
  &\quad \left. - 2 \cos (2 \sigma') \sin^2 (2 \phi) \sin (2 (\sigma - \sigma')) \right) \\
  &\quad + 2 \sin (2 \sigma') \cos (4 \phi') \left( -24 \sin^3 (\phi) (\cos (2 \sigma') \sin (\phi) - 4 \cos (\phi) \cos (\sigma - 2 \sigma')) \right. \\
  &\quad \left. + 8 \sin (2 \phi) (\sin (2 \phi) (\cos (2 \sigma) - 3 \cos (2 (\sigma - \sigma'))) + \cos (\sigma)) \right. \\
  &\quad \left. - 36 \cos (\sigma) \sin (4 \phi) + 36 \cos (2 \phi) + 23 \cos (4 \phi) + 5 \right) \\
  &\quad + 64 \sqrt{3} \cos (2 \sigma') \sin (\phi) \sin (2 \phi') (2 \cos (\sigma) \sin (2 \phi) - 3 \cos (2 \phi) - 1) \\
  &\quad \left( 2 \sin (\sigma) \cos (\sigma') \cos (\phi) + \sin (\sigma') (\sin (\phi) - 2 \cos (\sigma) \cos (\phi)) \right) \\
  &\quad + 32 \sqrt{3} \sin (2 \sigma') \sin (\phi) \sin (4 \phi') (-2 \cos (\sigma) \sin (2 \phi) + 3 \cos (2 \phi) + 1) \\
  &\quad \left( \cos (\sigma') \sin (\phi) - 2 \cos (\phi) \cos (\sigma - \sigma') \right) \\
  &\quad - 288 \sin^2 (\sigma') \cos (\sigma') (\sin (4 \phi) \sin (\sigma - \sigma') + \sin (\sigma') \cos (2 \phi)) \\
  &\quad - 2 \sin (2 \sigma') (8 \sin (2 \phi) (\sin (2 \phi) (9 \cos (2 (\sigma - \sigma')) + \cos (2 \sigma)) \\
  &\quad - 9 \cos (\sigma - 2 \sigma') + \cos (\sigma)) + 9 \cos (2 \sigma') (\cos (4 \phi) + 3) + 23 \cos (4 \phi) + 5) \bigg] \\
\end{split}     
\end{eqnarray}


This is just code. What is your question? Also, it is suggested not to use eqnarray.

As with your previous question, please add the missing lines, so your code will compile when we copy it. This means the documentclass, packages, \begin{document} etc. Also, please explain the problem more clearly. Do you get an error, or wrong output, how do you want the output to be? You say you want to use split but there is no split in the code, what exactly are you trying to do?

you should avoid eqnarray but if you are using amsmath and have an error with its split environment you should show a small document using that, and show the error that you get,

You never want to use eqnarray.
Removing all unnecessary \left and \right instructions and fixing the number of &, besides changing the incredibly wrong \text{$\phi'$} into \phi', I get a decent result.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  J_{cp} &= \frac{1}{36} \Bigl[\sqrt{3} \sin (2 \phi') (\sin (\sigma ) \cos (\sigma') \sin (2 \phi )-2 \sin (\sigma') \cos (2 \phi ))\\
  &\quad-3 \sin (\sigma ) \sin (2 \phi ) \cos (2 \phi')\Bigr]\\
  I_{1} &= \frac{1}{288}\Bigl[ 2 \sqrt{3} \sin (\phi) \sin (2 \phi') ( 8 \sin (2 \sigma) \cos (\sigma') \sin (\phi) \cos^2 (\phi)   \\
  &\quad   + 2 \sin (\sigma') ( 8 \cos (\sigma) \cos^3 (\phi) - 4 \cos (2 \sigma) \sin (\phi) \cos^2 (\phi) + \sin (\phi) + 5 \sin (3 \phi) )  \\
  &\quad   - 4 \sin (\sigma) \cos (\sigma') (\cos (\phi) + 3 \cos (3 \phi)) )  \\
  &\quad  + 6 \cos (2 \phi') ( \sin (4 \phi) (\sin (\sigma - 2 \sigma') - 3 \sin (\sigma))   \\
  &\quad   + \cos (\sigma') (-4 \sin (2 \phi) \sin (\sigma - \sigma') + 2 \sin (\sigma) \cos (4 \phi) \cos (\sigma - \sigma')   \\
  &\quad   - \sin (2 \sigma - \sigma') + 3 \sin (\sigma')) - 2 \sin (2 \sigma') \cos (2 \phi) )  \\
  &\quad  - 24 \sin (2 \sigma') \sin^3 (\phi) (2 \cos (\sigma) \cos (\phi) + \sin (\phi))  \\
  &\quad  - 12 \sin (2 \phi) ( \sin (\sigma) (\cos (2 \sigma') + 3) \cos (2 \phi) + \sin (\sigma') (\sin (2 \phi) \cos (2 \sigma - \sigma')) ) \\
  &\quad   + 2 \sin (\sigma) \sin (\sigma')  \Bigr]\\
  I_{2} &= \frac{1}{2304} \Bigl[ 96 \cos (2 \phi') ( \sin^3 (\phi) ( 8 \sin (\sigma) \cos^2 (2 \sigma') \cos (\phi)   \\
  &\quad   + \sin (4 \sigma') (\sin (\phi) - 4 \cos (\sigma) \cos (\phi)) )  \\
  &\quad  - 2 \cos (2 \sigma') \sin^2 (2 \phi) \sin (2 (\sigma - \sigma')) ) \\
  &\quad + 2 \sin (2 \sigma') \cos (4 \phi') ( -24 \sin^3 (\phi) (\cos (2 \sigma') \sin (\phi) - 4 \cos (\phi) \cos (\sigma - 2 \sigma'))  \\
  &\quad  + 8 \sin (2 \phi) (\sin (2 \phi) (\cos (2 \sigma) - 3 \cos (2 (\sigma - \sigma'))) + \cos (\sigma))  \\
  &\quad  - 36 \cos (\sigma) \sin (4 \phi) + 36 \cos (2 \phi) + 23 \cos (4 \phi) + 5 ) \\
  &\quad + 64 \sqrt{3} \cos (2 \sigma') \sin (\phi) \sin (2 \phi') (2 \cos (\sigma) \sin (2 \phi) - 3 \cos (2 \phi) - 1) \\
  &\quad ( 2 \sin (\sigma) \cos (\sigma') \cos (\phi) + \sin (\sigma') (\sin (\phi) - 2 \cos (\sigma) \cos (\phi)) ) \\
  &\quad + 32 \sqrt{3} \sin (2 \sigma') \sin (\phi) \sin (4 \phi') (-2 \cos (\sigma) \sin (2 \phi) + 3 \cos (2 \phi) + 1) \\
  &\quad ( \cos (\sigma') \sin (\phi) - 2 \cos (\phi) \cos (\sigma - \sigma') ) \\
  &\quad - 288 \sin^2 (\sigma') \cos (\sigma') (\sin (4 \phi) \sin (\sigma - \sigma') + \sin (\sigma') \cos (2 \phi)) \\
  &\quad - 2 \sin (2 \sigma') (8 \sin (2 \phi) (\sin (2 \phi) (9 \cos (2 (\sigma - \sigma')) + \cos (2 \sigma)) \\
  &\quad - 9 \cos (\sigma - 2 \sigma') + \cos (\sigma)) + 9 \cos (2 \sigma') (\cos (4 \phi) + 3) + 23 \cos (4 \phi) + 5) \Bigr] \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}



I suggest you switch to a single align* environment and be more circumspect about where you place the line breaks. I'd also get rid of all (yes, all) \left and \right sizing directives and get rid of most parentheses to declutter the appearance of the equations. And, don't be shy to use not only round parentheses but also square brackets and curly braces to provide some hierarchical visual structure on the expressions.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
J_{cp} 
  &= \frac{1}{36} \bigl\{\sqrt{3} \sin 2\phi' (\sin\sigma  \cos\sigma' \sin 2\phi -2 \sin\sigma' \cos 2\phi ) \\
 &\qquad-3 \sin\sigma \sin 2\phi \cos 2\phi' \bigr\} \\[\jot]
I_{1} &= \frac{1}{288}\bigl\{ 2 \sqrt{3} \sin\phi \sin 2\phi' \bigl[ 8 \sin 2\sigma \cos\sigma' \sin\phi \cos^2\phi\\
 &\qquad\quad + 2 \sin\sigma' ( 8 \cos\sigma \cos^3\phi - 4 \cos 2\sigma \sin\phi \cos^2\phi + \sin\phi + 5 \sin 3\phi )\\
 &\qquad\quad - 4 \sin\sigma \cos\sigma' (\cos\phi + 3 \cos 3\phi) \bigr]\\
 &\qquad + 6 \cos 2\phi' \bigl[ \sin 4\phi (\sin(\sigma-2\sigma') - 3 \sin\sigma )
  + \cos\sigma' (-4 \sin 2\phi \sin (\sigma-\sigma')\\
 &\qquad\quad + 2 \sin\sigma \cos 4\phi \cos (\sigma-\sigma')
  - \sin (2 \sigma-\sigma') + 3 \sin\sigma') - 2 \sin 2\sigma' \cos 2\phi \bigr]\\
 &\qquad - 24 \sin 2\sigma' \sin^3\phi (2 \cos\sigma \cos\phi + \sin\phi)\\
 &\qquad - 12 \sin 2\phi \bigl[ \sin\sigma (\cos 2\sigma' + 3) \cos 2\phi \\
 &\qquad\quad + \sin\sigma' (\sin 2\phi \cos (2 \sigma-\sigma')) \bigr]
  + 2 \sin\sigma \sin\sigma' \bigr\} \\[\jot]
I_{2} &= \frac{1}{2304} \bigl\{ 96 \cos 2\phi'
\bigl[ \sin^3\phi ( 8 \sin\sigma \cos^2 2\sigma' \cos\phi + \sin 4\sigma' (\sin\phi - 4 \cos\sigma \cos\phi) )\\
   &\qquad\quad - 2 \cos 2\sigma' \sin^2 2\phi \sin (2 (\sigma-\sigma')) \bigr]\\
   &\qquad + 2 \sin 2\sigma' \cos 4\phi'
   \bigl[ -24 \sin^3\phi (\cos 2\sigma' \sin\phi - 4 \cos\phi \cos(\sigma-2\sigma'))\\
   &\qquad\quad +8 \sin 2\phi \bigl( \sin 2\phi [\cos 2\sigma - 3\cos(2 (\sigma-\sigma'))] + \cos\sigma \bigr) \\
   &\qquad\quad -36 \cos\sigma \sin 4\phi + 36 \cos 2\phi + 23 \cos 4\phi + 5 \bigr] \\
   &\qquad + 64 \sqrt{3} \cos 2\sigma' \sin\phi \sin 2\phi' (2 \cos\sigma \sin 2\phi - 3\cos 2\phi - 1) \\
   &\qquad\quad \times 4\sigma' \bigl( 2\sin\sigma \cos\sigma' \cos\phi + \sin\sigma' (\sin\phi-2\cos\sigma \cos\phi) \bigr) \\
   &\qquad + 32 \sqrt{3} \sin 2\sigma' \sin\phi \sin 4\phi' (-2 \cos\sigma \sin 2\phi + 3 \cos 2\phi + 1) \\
   &\qquad\quad \times 4\sigma' \bigl( \cos\sigma' \sin\phi - 2 \cos\phi \cos (\sigma-\sigma') \bigr) \\
   &\qquad - 288 \sin^2\sigma' \cos\sigma' (\sin 4\phi \sin (\sigma-\sigma') + \sin\sigma' \cos 2\phi ) \\
   &\qquad - 2 \sin 2\sigma' \bigl[8 \sin 2\phi (\sin 2\phi (9 \cos (2 (\sigma-\sigma')) + \cos 2\sigma) \\
   &\qquad\quad - 9 \cos(\sigma-2\sigma') + \cos\sigma ) + 9 \cos 2\sigma' (\cos 4\phi + 3) + 23 \cos 4\phi + 5 \bigr] \bigr\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}

